# Dropdown Menu showing in md and lg, don't know how to fix it (Bootstra 3.6.6)

Tags: java, html, css

[Everything is fine in sm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfPXF.jpg)

[But when it comes to md and lg, this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yeE.jpg)

```css
#chicken {

background-color: rgb(52, 58, 58);

color: whitesmoke;

padding: 15px;

margin-bottom: 15px;

}

#chicken h6 {

font-size: 1.5em;

}

#titulo {

clear: right;

}

#butao {

background-color: rgb(207, 250, 248);

}

#header {

background-color: teal;

}
```

```html
<nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <!--titulo-->

      <h1 id="titulo">Food, LLC</h1>

      <!--butao-->

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#butao" aria-expanded="false">
    
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    
    </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="butao">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">

        <li>Chicken</li>

        <li>Beef</li>

        <li>Sushi</li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

I'm supposed to have a large desktop and a medium tablet like view without the light blue color on the upper side, just the darker one, and without the "ChikenBeefSushi" up there. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 because that's what the teacher uses and it only works in that version. My code is exactly like his, but his code works and I dont know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

md and lg it's bootstrap **not** fixed sized

md = for medium screen

lg = for large screen

and they are **floated** so you need clearfix

if you want to use sized it's used in css like

```
 font-size : 16 px;
 width : 200px;
 width : 20%;
```

.....

hope this is helpful

Comment: the thing is I want it to disappear in md and lg screens